# Using Nix to package CentOS5 toolchain dependencies

Tags: nix

We are currently investigating whether Nix can be a suitable tool for us to package third-party libraries and tools we need to build our software. Disclaimer: I just learned about Nix and still trying to put all the pieces together.

Our product needs to be ABI compatible with CentOS5 systems. That is why we build our software in a CentOS5 Docker container, with a custom built GCC, and a lot of other third-party tools and libraries all built from source.

Currently, we have one big Makefile to build all these dependencies, and use a CI job to build the dependencies. Every time one of the dependencies changes, or some change is done to the Makefile, we rebuild all dependencies which takes a long time.

Instead of improving the Makefile, we are looking into simpler solutions that are easier to maintain. I think Nix might be able to help us deal with this issue by translating the Makefile to separate derivations with the right dependencies specified per derivation. Would Nix be a suitable tool for this use case? The main problem I see is that Nix uses a modern glibc library as a base derivation, one on which we can not depend. Would we need to build a custom glibc version, or can we somehow depend on the glibc installed on the host system (the CentOS5 one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a scenario where Nix can help you.

> Our product needs to be ABI compatible with CentOS5 systems.

Binaries and libraries built by Nix (via Nixpkgs) do not link against system libraries. In effect, this is similar to static linking but achieved through different means, such as [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) and wrapper scripts. This should make your product ABI compatible with any distribution, unless your program explicitly requires certain operating system features other than normal libraries. For example, if your program depends on a GPU driver, that may still be a challenge.

> with a custom built GCC

Nixpkgs makes it possible to build all packages or just a selection with your custom GCC.

> with the right dependencies specified per derivation.

Nix is perfect for this task. I recommend building with the sandbox feature enabled. If you're not running NixOS, you should installed it in [multi-user mode](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sect-multi-user-installation) and enable sandboxing.

> The main problem I see is that Nix uses a modern glibc library as a base derivation, one on which we can not depend.

When built with Nix, your product will ignore the system glibc. Providing your own glibc is feasible, but I do not think you really need it, because you're building everything from source and compatibility with the host system is not an issue.

> or can we somehow depend on the glibc installed on the host system (the CentOS5 one)?

This is the approach taken on Mac OS X systems, out of necessity. Doing so would be considered a step back; you would need a good reason to do this.

> Would Nix be a suitable tool for this use case?

You should try it. Nix can provide you with at least these guarantees:

- All dependencies are specified
- Derivations built in parallel are equally correct
- Every build is a clean build, even when reusing results from earlier builds
- Reproducibility: if it builds today, it builds tomorrow and you can modify it tomorrow
- Complete dependencies: when installed, no dependencies will be left out

Good luck and don't hesitate to ask a question. Software often doesn't like to be coerced into proper behavior.

---

> and use a CI job

Full disclosure: I'm working on a CI service for Nix.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the elaborate answer. When you say "your product will ignore the system glibc" that would mean we need to package glibc from Nix with our product? glibc and other libraries will have to be transferred out of the Nix store into a separate `lib` directory for example bundled with the tool. This might require rewriting ELF headers I think? Is there some canonical way how to approach this? I am surprised there is little documentation on this subject. It seems most deployments include Nix itself as well, which in our case is not really an option.

Comment: I just found out that recent versions of glibc require more recent kernels during runtime. For example, from the announcement email of glibc 2.26 (https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-08/msg00010.html): 

"Linux kernel 3.2 or later is required at runtime, on all architectures supported by that kernel.  (This is a change from version 2.25 only for x86-32 and x86-64.)".

Since CentOS5 is using 2.6.18 IIRC, I do not think it is a good idea to bundle the glibc shipped with Nix with our application...

Comment: Hi Ton, I wasn't aware of the glibc kernel compatibility. The next best option is to provide an older glibc to Nixpkgs. I have written a derivation at a previous employer that turned a Nix closure into a single RPM package. That is sufficient when you don't have a risk of dependencies colliding with other such packages. You can build an RPM package for each derivation in the closure to make this scale beyond a single installed package if necessary.

Comment: Robert, interesting idea to use the RPM directly, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could use this technique as a basis to generate RPM packages for each derivation: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/92a047a6c4d46a222e9c323ea85882d0a7a13af8/pkgs/build-support/closure-info.nix